# Minecraft won't run on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, minecraft

I've had minecraft running on 12.04 for ages, but since upgrading to 14.04 it won't start. I'm using Oracle Java 8, but I've tried Oracle Java 7 and the default Java 7 that comes with Ubuntu.

Here's the error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/myuser/minecraft/.minecraft/versions/1.8.3/1.8.3-natives-1013592580460/liblwjgl.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/myuser/minecraft/.minecraft/versions/1.8.3/1.8.3-natives-1013592580460/liblwjgl64.so: /home/myuser/minecraft/.minecraft/versions/1.8.3/1.8.3-natives-1013592580460/liblwjgl64.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at avf.J(SourceFile:2524)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
```

I've tried it with and without

```
apt-get install liblwjgl-java liblwjgl-java-jni
```

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome, but have also tried running from OpenBox.

My computer is an Intel i3 with 4GB RAM and 'normal' Intel graphics. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. On 12.04 Minecraft ran fine (not buttery smooth, but it's not a high spec machine and was easily playable)